# Install Oracle 11g Client on Windows 10

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, windows-10, oracleclient

Is it possible to install Oracle 11g client on Windows 10?  Our firm's computers were upgraded to Windows 10 and our ODBC access no longer works.  I then tried to use my personal PC (Win 10) to install the client and see if it works; however, after downloading the files and running setup.exe, a command window opens and closes immediately.  I don't see any errors but it doesn't install either.

[Some research shows that it may not be supported](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47798/reqs.htm#NTDBI2698) but if that's the case, how should we connect to our 11g database?

Any and all insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to install an outdated version of Oracle? You can connect with an Oracle 12 client to an Oracle 11 database without any problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'll try that on my personal computer to ensure it will work, but to answer your question, it usually takes a couple of months for our IT department to approve software and then install it for us and since we already have 11g installed, it would be in our best interest to get our 11g clients working again in the interim of 12c being installed.  Do you think there's any chance in that?

Comment: Windows 10 was released in 2015, Oracle 11.2 was released 2009. I think it should work - I don't know to on extend the Oracle documents are updated.

Comment: Is this the full Oracle client or just the Instant client? Also, does your personal laptop run Wind Professional? Oracle enterprise software isn't certified again Home edition

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - Oracle 11g client can not install on Windows 10, for Windows 10 we need to take only Oracle client 12